# Why does reading a line of input from /dev/zero make my computer unresponsive?

Tags: rust, readline, eof

When building this code:

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let res = io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
}
```

and then executing:

```
cargo run < /dev/zero
```

My computer (under Ubuntu 20) becomes unresponsive.

I have read [the manual page of the `readline` function](https://docs.rs/rl-sys/0.5.2/rl_sys/readline/index.html) and this behavior doesn't seem normal.

What am I missing?

Comment: The whole computer becomes unresponsive?

Comment: It is working fine for me on OSX

Comment: The `read_line` you're calling is documented here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line. It has nothing to do with GNU readline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/dev/zero` is a never-ending stream of `NUL` bytes. `read_line` stops when it reads a newline symbol. So, this function will never return and will try to infinitely expand the buffer. The reason your computer becomes unresponsive is likely because it starts [swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Address_space_swapping) heavily, in order to accommodate the ever-growing buffer.

`read_line()` is definitely not what you want. Try reading a fixed amount of bytes instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it perfectly fills my understanding of this Rust function.